# Search and highlight - Client vs. Server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web application that shows ~ 2000 lines "divs", and I want to make the user able to search and highlight the keywords. I tried using jQuery plugins for this but the performance was really bad and IE got almost hung! So, I was wondering if this is the best way to do it? and If am not getting a faster version I'd rather do it on the server "AJAX call" and re-render the whole lines again - this way at least the user won't feel the browser is getting hung!

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: for me AJAX is already a good solution for this one.

Comment: If your DOM tree is that huge, server side with AJAX call will work best, for small documents you can always go client as it is less trouble.

Comment: well, yeah! it's huge! and i'd need to cache that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this via an AJAX call to the server, providing the highlight keyword string and returning the divs, something like this:

```
$("#content").load('page.aspx', {'keywords':$('#searchBox').val()});
```

In this approach your server would return only the divs (with highlighting!) based on the passed `keywords` string, and this would populate the `<div id="content">` with them.

The highlighting on the client is cheap, but *searching for what to highlight* is extremely expensive in javascript, that's a lot of DOM crawling going on.  Doing this via the server on a timeout would be the best approach, so it doesn't do it as they're typing every keystroke, something like this:

```
$('#searchBox').unbind('keyup').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
  var wait = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#content").load('page.aspx', {'keywords':$('#searchBox').val()}); 
  }, 150);
  $(this).data('timer', wait);
});
```

This would perform a server callback, but only 150ms after the user stops typing.  I find this a comfortable interval, but adjust as needed...or bind the function directly to the `click` event of something...whatever best suits your interface :)